# Problem Using Promise to Set Global Variable

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to use a function to populate a global variable, then call subsequent functions once that is complete.  The code I currently have is:

```
$(function () {
    var jsonData = {};

    var dataRetrievalPromise = function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
             jsonData = { "data": [{ "test": "value1" }, { "test2": "value2" }, { "test3": "value3" }] }
             return resolve(jsonData);
        });       
     }

    dataRetrievalPromise().then(function (result) {
         generateTabs();
    });
});

function generateTabs() {
    var test = jsonData;
};
```

dataRetrievalPromise successfully sets the value of jsonData, however when i try to access jsonData within generateTabs() then it shows as undefined.

Edit: forgot resolve statement
Edit 2: Fixed punctation in post, punctation in my code is/was correct, so problem remains.

As per Adiga's suggestion replaced dataRetrievalPromise with below, but behavior is the same.

```
var dataRetrievalpromise = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        return resolve(jsonData = { "data": [{ "test": "value1" }, { "test2": "value2" }, { "test3": "value3" }] });
    });
};
```

Comment: You never `resolve` the Promise.

Comment: `resolve(jsonData = { "data":[] } )`

Comment: Accidentally omitted the resolve statement in my original question, added.

Comment: `dataRetrievalPromise().then()` line never runs because it's inside `dataRetrievalPromise` after the `return` statement. Please post a [mcve]  which compliles. There are several missing brackets. Not sure if that is causing the issue or something else

Comment: Indent your code and please make sure that you have put everything correctly.  adiga's comment is correct, but I'm not sure that's the actual answer since you might have accidentally missed a closing brace.

Comment: It would be more correct to say that `jsonData` was a variable in a surrounding closure, instead of a global variable. It is 'global-ish' as you are using it across multiple internal functions, but not truly a global, as it cannot be accessed outside of the outermost function.

Comment: Thanks Garrett, you are indeed correct.  Moving the variable to outside of the $(function(){}) scope fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use a function to populate a global variable

No, don't do that. (Your code in fact works apart from the fact that you declared `jsonData` inside the scope of the `$(function () {…})`, not as a global variable). But still, you should not use a global variable here which is populated at an unknown point in time (when the promise resolves). Instead, just pass the promise result as an argument to the function that you subsequently call:

```
function retrieveData() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve({ "data": [{ "test": "value1" }, { "test2": "value2" }, { "test3": "value3" }] });
    });       
}

retrieveData().then(function (result) {
     generateTabs(result);
//                ^^^^^^
});

function generateTabs(jsonData) {
    var test = jsonData;
}
```

Comment: Admittedly I do not have much experience determining the overall data flow in a scenario like this, but despite that using a global variable does seem less than ideal.  I understand your example above but the problem is that in my solution there are numerous functions which need to consume this json.  Would you suggest that all of the functions should simply take the json returned from retrieveData() as a parameter?

Comment: @user3626232 Yes, that's probably the cleanest solution, calling all those functions in the `then` callback. That's assuming they are relatively simple function with the json as their only dependency, and that they would be called immediately on startup anyway.